# Xcode: How do I include a framework in my application

Tags: xcode, frameworks, sdl

I am new to Xcode programming and have finished my first game wich uses SDL. When starting it on another mac it didn't work until I added the SDL2.framework into the /Library/Framework directory. Now I've been searching forever on how I could include the framework in the app because I didn't want to install the SDL2.framework on every mac I wanted to play the game on but I didn't find anything that worked… I've found something like "turn off ZeroLink" but didn't find it in Xcode… What setting do I have to change so Xcode will include the framework in the finished .app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial details setting up an SDL project in Xcode and the final, optional section, covers packaging the framework with the app

http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/

Essentially what you need to do is:

- Create a *Copy Files* entry in the build phases
- Set the *Destination* field to be **Frameworks**
- Add the **SDL2.framework** in the list to be copied
- Set the parameter *Runpath Search Paths* (under Linking in the Build Settings) to be **@executable_path/../Frameworks**

[image]

Comment: Hmm the app still doesn't work on other macs… I have tried unchecking the "Copy only when installing" checkbox -> xcode included the SDL2.framework in x.app/Contents/Frameworks but still the app wouldn't work on a different mac.

Comment: Will I have to change the "Framework Search Paths"? If I do have to change it please tell me what needs to be changed.

Comment: @leo0230 I set it to `/Library/Frameworks` however I think the thing you need to set is **Runpath Search Paths** - set this as `@executable_path/../Frameworks`